# Algorithm help :Given a num, can it finally be 1

Tags: algorithm

Given a number, you can divide it or its contiguous part by 2 , or multiply it or its continuous part by 2. Can the number finally be 1?

For example : 13

```
3 is a part of 13, first we take 3 * 2 = 6, the num turn to be 16,
second we can operate the whole num 16, 16 / 2 = 8, the num is 8 now,
8/2 = 4, num is 4 now,
4/2 = 2, num is 2 now,
2/2 = 1, num is 1 now.

finally we can say 13 can turn into 1, and the path is 13->16->8->4->2->1, we can use a List to store the path.
```

Example ：27

```
first we operate the whole num 27, 27 * 2 = 54；
then we take 4 as the part of 54, 4 / 2 = 2 , so the 4 is 2 now, num becomes 52;
operate 52, 52 / 2 = 26, num is 26 now；
operate 26, 26 / 2 = 13, num is 13 now；

we just analyzed 13, so 27 can turn into 1 finally.
```

How to analyze such problem? What's the main idea of solving such type problem?

---

Sorry about the confusing description, let's take a more complex example: 316

16 is a contiguous part, let 16 / 2 = 8 , so the num is 38 now,

then take 8 / 2 = 4 , the num is 34,

take 4 / 2 = 2, the num is 32,

now take the whole num 32 / 2 = 16,

16 / 2 = 8， num is 8,

8 / 2 = 4, num is 4,

4 / 2 = 2, num is 2,

finally 2 / 2 = 1.

We say, original num 316 can turn into 1 finally after above conversion.

And the contiguous part means, if the input num is `12345`,

then `123`, `234`,`345`,`12`,`2345` and so on, they are all contiguous parts.

Any continuous subset of num is fine，including head or tail is NOT necessary.

---

The question is :

1. How to judge such a num? And if the num can turn into 1, print the path.
2. Can you find the shortest way?

---

I got some hints from interviewer (The interview is over):

1. Most of numbers are eligible, that means nums which are NOT eligible, these characteristics are obvious.
2. Brute fore way's time complexity is too high, we should pruning timely. (Slide window + pruning ?)

Comment: Add your code/approach, and the issue you're running into

Comment: I don't know how to solve above algorithm, so I'm asking for help, bro.

Comment: What do you mean by `continuous part` here?

Comment: When you multiply or divide by 2, does the continuous part have to remain the same length? For example, can you go from 52 to 102 (and vice-versa)?

Comment: Did you mean "contiguous" part -- i.e., some set of digits that are all adjacent. E.g., if the number is 1234, you could affect 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 23, 34, 123, 234, or 1234, but not 1 & 3.

Comment: Why are you dividing 4 / 2 and not 54 / 2? (in your second example)

Comment: If we multiply the 7 in 17 by 2, do we get 24 (or 114)?

Comment: Your example is very confusing as all the posts has indicated, please try to answer them and get a clear one.

Comment: The likely answer is, "breadth-first search" but you need to specify your operation better.  If you just need to find A path and not the shortest, the answer switches to A* search.

Comment: Sorry about the confusing desc, I have updated it.

Comment: @Jozott  54 / 2  = 27  is a way too , I just pick an eligible way,  there are various way, but not all of  them are eligible.

Comment: @Dave  You are right, it's my fault to make confusing desc.  And we get 114 for your case

Comment: One idea is to turn the number into a power of 2, so that you can keep dividing by 2 to eventually get to 1, or turn the number into any number from a table of _pre-computed_, known values, and then using the stored operations for those values, we can eventually get to 1. Apart from this, I can't think of any polynomial time algorithm that is guaranteed to do this

Comment: @xiaobinyáng And if you double a "continuous part", can its length change?

Comment: Also are you looking for **a** path or a **shortest** path?

Comment: @btilly sure it is, that's the tricky part,  shortest path is optional.

Comment: Okay, so "continuous" to you means a subsection of the string of digits? Any substring? Like for number 316, is 31 a legitimate continuous part, or does it always have to include the last digit?

Comment: @Elliott Any subSet of num

Comment: Just wanted to point out that there is a shorter path for 27: _(214 -> 224 -> 112 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1)_. Anyways like I said, I see no feasible polynomial time algorithm, but it is looking like some sort of graph problem, with path pruning as an optimization step

Comment: @smac89 Smart thought !   Forgive my greediness, can you explain your thought more concise ?  How to divide the original input into sub problem ?  that's bother me.

Comment: What I was thinking was to use the method defined by @btilly where we use breadth-first search, with a pruning algorithm which is based on _edit distance_. We will also keep track of which nodes we generated at each level (this helps with knowing explored nodes). By "edit distance", I mean: _explore the next node to which is closest to a power of two_. So if you start with 23, you will generate the following possible nodes: _46, 26, 43, 13_. Of all the nodes generated 13 is closest to 16, so we explore it first in the next round.

Comment: After we generate nodes on the current level, we check if any of the generated nodes have already been explored in previous levels, and if so, we ignore those, or mark them as "explored".
Now for the pruning, I propose a very simple one: Just look at the last digit of each number. If multiplying it by 2 or dividing it by two leads to a new last digit ending in _2,4,6,or 8_, take it. I ignore 0 because I don't think any number ending in 0 will ever lead to a solution. Therefore any number ending in 5 should also be ignored because they will eventually lead back to number ending in 0...

Comment: I didn't pass the interview, but I still want to figure the problem out, I have searched related key words, but nothing found. so I asked for help, am I wrong ? @Elliott

Comment: @xiaobinyáng, if you're no longer in the interview process then I can't see the problem with that. It might be worth noting that in your question where you talk about the interviewer. Personally I see a lot of cheating with SO and some people get interview problems that they have 24/48 hours to do.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your advice, that's NOT the way I live. @Elliott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple and unoptimized breadth-first search.

```py
def shortest_digit_path (n):
    path_from = {n: None}
    queue = [n]
    count = 0
    while True:
        m = queue.pop(0)
        count += 1
        if 0 == count %1000:
            print((count, m))

        if m == 1:
            break
        x = str(m)
        for i in range(len(x)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(x) + 1):
                y = x[0:i]
                z = x[i:j]
                w = x[j:]

                if z[0] == '0':
                    continue # The continuous section is not a proper number.

                # Try half of z
                if z[-1] in ['2', '4', '6', '8']:
                    next_m = int(y + str(int(z)//2) + w)
                    if next_m not in path_from:
                        path_from[next_m] = m
                        queue.append(next_m)

                # Try doubling z
                next_m = int(y + str(int(z)*2) + w)
                if next_m not in path_from:
                    path_from[next_m] = m
                    queue.append(next_m)

    path = []
    while m is not None:
        path.append(m)
        m = path_from[m]
    return list(reversed(path))
```

After playing around with this for a bit, I came up with the following observations.

1. If the number ends in `0` or `5`, there is no path to having any other digit at the end, and therefore you can't get to 1.  (The above function will just run forever.
2. For anything else we can find a path just dealing with 1-2 digits at a time.

Here are the special cases for observation #2.  Our first goal is to get to just 0, 1, and 5 as digits.

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2 -> 1
3: 3 -> 6 -> 12 -> 24 -> 28 -> 56 -> 112 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
4: 4 -> 2 -> 1
5: 5
6: 6 -> 12 -> 24 -> 28 -> 56 -> 112 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
7: 7 -> 14 -> 28 -> 56 -> 112 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
8: 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
9: 9 -> 18 -> 28 -> 56 -> 112 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

And now from the start of the number we have to deal with the following cases that reduce the number of digits and get back to our desired form.

```
10: 10 -> 5
11: 11 -> 22 -> 24 -> 28 -> 56 -> 112 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
15: 15 -> 110 -> 220 -> 240 -> 280 -> 560 -> 1120 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5
50: 50 -> 25 -> 15 -> 110 -> 220 -> 240 -> 280 -> 560 -> 1120 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5
51: 51 -> 52 -> 26 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
55: 55 -> 510 -> 520 -> 260 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5
```

With this set of rules we can first normalize the number to a standard form, then we can shorten it one digit at a time.  This lets us essentially instantly come up with a path.  Almost certainly not the shortest one, but definitely a path.

Writing that function is left as an exercise to the reader.

Now back to the shortest path.  The algorithm for the breadth-first search can be made much faster if we start with a breadth-first search from both ends and meet in the middle.  For this you'd need to also have a `path_to` that is initialized with `{1: None}`, a queue containing elements of the form `(m, is_rising)` and initialize it with `[(1, True), (n: False)]`.  You'd then have to branch on `is_rising` and before entering values into `path_from/path_to` check for whether it is in `path_to/path_from`.  If it is, you've met in the middle.  Now work out both halves of the path and join them together.

The approach is tricker.  But it will let you find the shortest path in the square root of the number of steps that the current approach takes.